# ¿Cómo pasar un string a dict con un int value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, diccionarios

Estoy desarrollando un bot y lo único que consigo hacer es pasar un `string` a `dict` el cual me convierte los valores numéricos a `string` también, no soy muy experimentado con este tipo de transformaciones así que agradezco vuestra ayuda:

Tengo los datos en una db y necesito pasar el `inv` que está guardado como `string` a un `dict`.

```
result = await self.db.fetch(f'SELECT * FROM members')
        for id, bal, xp, lvl, nave, inv, lugar, vida, ataque, defensa, arma, armadura  in result:
            self.me.SPC.members[id] = self.MemberClass(bal, xp, lvl, nave, self.InvToDict(inv), lugar, vida, ataque, defensa, arma, armadura)
```

La función que uso es la siguiente:

```
def InvToDict(self, inv, res=[]):
        """ Inventory String to Dict """
        
        result = dict(map(str.strip, sub.split(':', 1)) for sub in inv.split(',') if ':' in sub)

        return dict(result)
```

El problema viene en que obtengo como resultado por ejemplo `{'Metal': '200', 'Gold': '100'}` por lo que no puedo modificar los valores con operaciones, probé varias cosas pero solo consigo errores, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los diccionarios son inmutables, no puedes cambiar las claves pero si los valores de estas. Podrías agregar cual es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: @christian me gustaría obtener {'Metal': 200, 'Gold': 100} para poder operar con esos valores y no {'Metal': '200', 'Gold': '100'}

Comment: Ok el valor que obtengas deberás pasarlo a entero con la funcion `int(valor)`

Comment: ¿Cómo es la cadena que está recibiendo la función en el parámetro `inv`? Parece que el uso de `map` puede no ser lo mejor aquí, pero para aconsejarte bien sería necesario ver cómo es esa cadena.

Comment: [christian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/183782/christian) los diccionarios en python no son inmutables, por ejemplo puedes eliminar una clave con `del`